# Thinking Sphinx Search Box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to get Thinking Sphinx running on my site but I'm not sure how to set up the search box and button for the index page. I have in my model:

```
 define_index do
   indexes :name
   indexes description
   where "approved = 'true'"
 end
```

In my controller:

```
def index
  @businesses = Business.search params[:search]
end
```

And in my index.html.erb I installed the autocomplete plugin and have:

```
<h3>Search Business</h3><%= text_field_with_auto_complete :name %>
```

I just don't know how to link up my text box with Sphinx. Do I need to create a button? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ryan Bates has a [Railscast on Thinking Sphinx](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx) that should set you in the right direction. You can [view the source code for the form](http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/af75076c6171a9dcf61668c3f43c4b646405f838/episode-120/blog/app/views/articles/index.html.erb) in Ryan's example:

```
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
```

Comment: Already watched it. He never shows his code on his index page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know all the code was contained on github.  After referencing that it helped, but my code still didn't work. I had to run thinking_sphinx:rebuild.